# Ceiling Fan Wiring Confusion

Tags: wiring, lighting, ceiling-fan

Was expecting to find just 3 simple wires (b, w, g) and be able to hook up this ceiling fan quite easily but found this when taking out the old fan...3 sets of wires, #1 with 2 black and 1 white, #2 with 2 white, and #3 with 1 black. How would I go about wiring this to the new ceiling fan? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Please consider [merging your unregistered and registered accounts](/help/merging-accounts), which will allow you to [edit](/help/privileges/create-posts), [comment on](/help/privileges/comment) any of your posts and [accept an answer](/help/someone-answers) on your question. Thanks, and welcome to the site!

Answer (score 4):

The 2 black + 1 white is your **always-hot bundle**.  You won't use it (unless you want to power the fan 24x7 and use a remote on it).

The 2 white is the **neutral bundle**.  Your fan will need that.

The loose black is the **switched-hot** from the switch. (it is the partner wire to the oddball white from above).  This is the switched-hot for the fan.

The switch is a *switch loop*, meaning power comes to the fan (and also goes onward to serve other things)... and the switch merely gets always-hot and switched-hot.  It was legal to wire switches that way as recently as 2011.  The white could be a real source of confusion, since it's *not* a neutral, so two special rules apply: #1 the always-hot wire must be white (to make it more obvious that it's not a neutral to people probing it with voltage testers), and #2 the white wire must be marked with black tape or paint to indicate it's a hot.

Without that marking, which was overlooked in your box, it is impossible to distinguish a switch loop from other wires.  So it is most important you don't allow the 2 black + 1 white to become separated/confused. It is common for important information like this to only exist in wire position. This is why I own 10 colors of tape.

Comment: yes, now would be a good time to mark that white wire with a black paint marker or some black tape.  if you're also replacing the fan control do it there too.

Comment: So if the fan I bought has 2 ground (green), 1 blue + 1 black, and 1 white wire, how would I go about connecting the wires via nuts, to the mentioned 2 bundles and switch? Thanks again!

Comment: Is is no longer legal to run a switch loop (with no neutral)? If not, I'm assuming there's now a requirement that the circuit neutral has to be present in every junction box.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart That would be relevant if he was wiring a switch loop. He's installing a fan.  The switch loop wiring is "grandfathered", the mere fact that Code changes does not oblige you to retrofit everything that was installed before.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Yes, due to the increasing popularity of smart switches, dimmers, etc, which all require a neutral, it is now required to have a neutral in all boxes to allow the option for the homeowner to install such devices.

Comment: Thanks @J... Do you know in what version of the NEC this changed? Harper Note that I said *run* implying "newly install".

Comment: @JonathonReinhart In the US the NEC rule change was 2011, see article 404.2(C).