# Ceiling Fan Wiring Confusion P2

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel, ceiling-fan

The 2 black + 1 white is my always-hot bundle. I won't use it (unless I want to power the fan 24x7 and use a remote on it). The 2 white is the neutral bundle. My fan will need that. The loose black is the switched-hot from the switch. (it is the partner wire to the oddball white from above). This is the switched-hot for the fan.

So if my fan came with a generic 1 black, 1 blue, 1 white, and 2 green ground wires, how would I go about connecting them to the neutral bundle and switched-hot? I’d assume the black and blue goto the switch and the white to the neutral bundle, but where would the ground goto? Thanks for helping this novice!

[image: ![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcTYw.jpg)]

[image]

Comment: You have the gist. Does your fan have any on board switches or remotes to control any functions?

Comment: The old ceiling fan had a remote but this one does not and the only switch it has on the fan is to switch the direction the blades spin.

Comment: Original question https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/170025/ceiling-fan-wiring-confusion/170029?noredirect=1#comment290450_170029

Comment: It appears you accidentally created a second account, probably because you're using cookie-based "soft accounts" instead of real accounts tied to an email.  If you're going to frequently reset your cookies or hop devices or hop browsers, I'd create a full account. Then ask the mods to merge your accounts, so you get reputation credit, notifications etc.

Comment: Please consider [merging your unregistered and registered accounts](/help/merging-accounts), which will allow you to [edit](/help/privileges/create-posts), [comment on](/help/privileges/comment) any of your posts and [accept an answer](/help/someone-answers) on your question. Thanks, and welcome to the site!

Comment: @harper Thanks for taking the extra time to help a new user to the site. However, moderators can't merge user accounts. Stack Exchange staff has to do that, and it's best if the OP contacts them directly via the "Contact" link at the bottom of the page, then one of the options for the type of help is "I need to merge user profiles".

Answer (score 1):

### White

obvious

### Green(s)

Look to see if any ground wires are present in the junction box.  If any, attach to them and also attach the metal box to them.

If no wires but an obvious metallic pipe entering box, then attach to the metal box via a #10-32 screw; they sell suitable green-painted screws 10 for a buck, or 10 for $3 with cute little ground pigtails attached.

If no evidence of any ground, then hmmm. Leave it detached; this is better than "islanding a ground", which wouldn't actually ground anything and would only cause the islanded locations to share ground faults.

### Blue and Black

One of them powers the fan.  The other does nothing; or it powers a light which you haven't mentioned.

If you want the thing switched by the switch, attach it to the switched-hot wire.  Your other option is to connect it to always-hot and let it run 24x7 or control it via another means.

Given that you only have one light switch, it appears you must switch fan and light together, unless you want to obtain some sort of remote or smart switch with a companion fan module up there, and use that to separately control fan and light. In that case, ask how to wire it - it'll be quite different.

Building Codes absolutely require that a light switch, in the obvious, usual location, operate a practical light in the room. That is not to save you from yourself, that is for the safety and benefit of your guests and to help first responders do their job.

The only exception to the "light switch" rule is if you are willing to hardwire the lighting on and burn it 24x7, but a nightlight won't do, it needs to be practical room lighting.